# Removing the "ARTICLE HISTORY COMPILED (date)" from the latex of my article

Tags: compiling, templates, article, datetime, elsarticle

I have written my article with a template that was provided by the editor. In this template, whenever you run the latex file, the compiled history will be written. However, now the editor has asked me to delete this. I have searched the internet and also have tried \date{} but no useful results are seen. The issue is shown in the following image. 
Thanks in advance[image: The image]
[The link of the template](http://www.nippyzip.com/uploads/170921084309-82595.zip)

I have found the command in the style.cls that brings this extra information but I dont know how to eliminate it from the cls file. The part that is written ARTICLE HISTORY is responsible.

```
    \def\@maketitle{\thispagestyle{plain}
  \clearpage
  \null
  \bgroup
    \parindent0pt
    \vspace*{36pt}
    {\articletypefont{\@articletype}\par}%
    \vskip13pt
    {\titlefont{\@title}\par}%
    \vskip13pt
    {\authorfont\@author\par}%
    \ifsuppldata\else
    \vskip17pt
 {\receivedfont{\bfseries ARTICLE HISTORY\\}\@received\par}%
   \fi
    \vskip13pt
  \egroup}
```

Comment: Well, if the editor sends you a template which prints that part, it should be the editor's job to remove the thing. Anyway, it's impossible to answer without knowing the template itself.

Comment: You are right but this was the request of the editor. However, the template is added.

Comment: A ZIP from some third party site? I don't think I would download it, sorry.

Comment: Yes because they have emailed me this template and I couldn't find it on the original website. So, unfortunately, that was the only choice.

Comment: check the updated post, please!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the explanation in the template itself, you just need to supply the `suppldata` class option.

```
\documentclass[suppldata]{interact}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, you are right. Much better solution than mine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok I will answer my own post. I edited the part related to the \maketitle command as the following and it now works perfectly.

```
\def\@maketitle{\thispagestyle{plain}
  \clearpage
  \null
  \bgroup
    \parindent0pt
    \vspace*{36pt}
    {\articletypefont{\@articletype}\par}%
    \vskip13pt
    {\titlefont{\@title}\par}%
    \vskip13pt
    {\authorfont\@author\par}%
    \ifsuppldata\else
    \vskip17pt
 {\receivedfont{\bfseries }}%
   \fi
    \vskip0pt
  \egroup}
```

Comment: That's not really helpful! Your local version may compile without the article history now, but the editor does not have your changed template -- and I doubt he would change his version. :-)

Comment: You have to consider that editor is interested in the final package of my article not the history of the article. I sent it now and they accepted it :-)